# Why do I have Text Shadow on My Graphics Banner in Rebol while I use shadow 0x0?

Tags: rebol

I use this code:

```
view layout [

    box sky 200x100  
    font [
      shadow 0x0
      align: 'center 
      size: 16 
      color: blue 
      colors: [255.255.255 255.255.255]
    ] "Test Shadow"
]
```

But still get shadow. Is it possible to get rid off it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is an error in your code. You might save yourself sometime if you check your code before posting here.

Try

```
shadow: 0x0
```

Comment: I'm too used to IDE in other languages that makes my brain lazy to even detect basic syntax error :)

Comment: It did give no error, I would expect him to say something bad then I would have known.

Comment: Would you expect a C compiler (or JavaScript) to notice that if you wrote (if x = -1) instead of (if x == -1)?

I think Rebol is good, but it's not clairvoyant!

Comment: The Compiler no but Visual Studio or VBA IDE yes :)

Comment: Still my question is not answered ;) I would like multiple lines with MULTIPLE fonts / colors.

Comment: I've given you a workable suggestion in the comments to the other question you posted about this and have recently added the essence of the answer for you.